# How to go back to the previous view where i was before giving my passcode

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

i am new in ios development. I am making an app where user needs to provide app passcode if user kept the app in background for 2 minutes. now my problem is, after giving the app passcode i  want my app back to last view where the app was before kept in background , so i want to do like when user give wright passcode it will go back the view where the app was. i don't know how to implement it? please help me.

Comment: please tell us how you display the passcode view

Comment: user's passcode has been saved in local db and after successfully register if the app kept in background for 2 minutes it will ask for app passcode which is saved in local db if the passcode match the passcode page is destroy and display the last view which was seen before app goes in background.

Comment: HOW does it ask for the passcode? how do you present that view?

Comment: Did you do a push segue or modal?

Comment: i am asking for passcode in a text box  and checking if the text box value is same as database passcode value and i am check it in a button action if passcode match it will go back to the last view.

Comment: yes i did.. but if i use segue i can only call a particular view which i don't want to do this i want to show the last view in button action.